# Use flash on a wordpress site as a widget

Tags: plugins, flash

I have a banner from a site and it's in flash (.swf file). I want to have this banner onto the widget bar. I'm currently using WP-SWFObject plugin, but it only works on the homepage. If someone goes to another page, the flash is not working. How can I use this flash banner on my site (with or without a plugin).

Thx and sorry for my bad english (not my native language)

Answer (score 1):

Create a [widget without an input filter](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/19207/adding-iframe-content-to-sidebar-widget/19210#19210) and add your banner code to it.

And welcome to WordPress Stack Exchange! :)

Comment: I have Magic Widgets and Unfiltered text, plus my swf file on the server. Now what to do?

Comment: @emil Insert the banner code into the text widget and that widget into a sidebar. Make sure you are using an absolute path to the SWF file.