# YouTube Sidebar Widget - YouTube service unavailable

Tags: plugins, videos, youtube

I'm using WordPress 3.5 and [YouTube Sidebar Widget 1.3.2](http://wordpress.org/support/plugin/youtube-sidebar-widget).

The plugin display service is unavailable. Why have I encountered service unavailable? The YouTube video is set to be public and embeddable.

Comment: Have you tried [adding the video as HTML](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/19210/73)? Without more information we cannot answer your question.

Comment: Suggestion: report the workaround bellow to the plugin author.

Comment: It seems the plugin is no longer under maintance.

Answer (score 3):

The plugin uses cURl direkt instead of WordPress' built in HTTP class. If your sever does not support cURL, the plugin can not work and you got this message. Deinstall the plugin and use another one. Or replace the `curl_it()` function within the plugin with something stable.

**Update**

The workaraound:

Open the plugin file `youtube-sidebar-widget.php` and replace the function `curl_it()` with this:

```
function curl_it($url) {

  $data = wp_remote_get( $url );

  return ( ! is_wp_error( $data ) && isset( $data['body'] ) ) ?
    $data['body'] : false;

}
```